# How to group multiple documents if an array within them contains an element which is present in another document's array?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to group multiple documents by addresses present in each document. However, the addresses are sub-documents themselves, and stored in an array. I require to group two documents together if they have even one same address present in their arrays, but not necessarily in the same index. Could this be done? The general structure of a document is as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ccb0983258f7a1694f30e7d"),
"name" : {
    "first" : "John",
    "middle" : "J",
    "last" : "Doe",
    "prefix" : "Mr.",
    "professionalSuffixes" : [ 
        "MD"
    ],
    "generationalSuffix" : "Jr"
},
"ssn" : "123-45-6789",
"birthDate" : "1996-06-28",
"gender" : "Unknown",
"maritalStatus" : "Separated",
"postalAddresses" : [ 
    {
        "streetAddress" : [ 
            "23 LeeWay RD", 
            "APT 342"
        ],
        "officeSuite" : "4743",
        "apartmentNumber" : "022",
        "postOfficeBoxNumber" : "12345",
        "postalCode" : "12345",
        "city" : "St Louis",
        "state" : {
            "code" : "MO",
            "name" : "Missouri",
            "description" : "Test Description"
        },
        "country" : {
            "name" : "United States of America",
            "iso2Code" : "US",
            "iso3Code" : "USA",
            "description" : "Test Description"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to deal with a situation as follows: there are 3 docs, where #1 and #2 share an address, #2 and #3 share an address. but #1 and #3 don't. would you want them all in the same group still? if not just use unwind on the address field before grouping.

Comment: The grouping is simple: if two docs contain an address which is same, they would be present in a grouping. In the example you provided, there would be two groups, and 2 would be present in both of them: [1,2], [2,3].

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking without a clear example and expected result. You really should show at least a couple of documents that you would expect to "group" and at least one thing that would not, and therefore be in it's own "grouping". It really comes down to what your expectation of a "unique address" actually is. Also does not hurt to actually show any attempt you may have made, since this gives some idea as to what you might expect ( in addition to the source and output samples ) as well as indicating "some effort", and which parts you might need help with.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, as I explained in the previous comment, it's a simple grouping. Showing two enormous documents, and trying to explain the connections between them would have complicated my question to the point that it would be unreadable at best and unintelligible at worst. Also, I was not able to put in effort, as I really was not getting any idea how to do this. Also, there were no other Stackoverflow questions which I could have referred. I did search for them, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment responding to mine you just need to unwind the field first:

```
{
 $unwind: "$postalAddresses"
},
{ 
  $group: {
     _id: group_cond,
     docs_ids: {$push: "$_id"}
  }
}
```

Now group condition should be whatever makes an address "unique", 
it should look a little something like this:

```
{ country: "$postalAddresses.country.name", state: "$postalAddresses.state.code", city: "$postalAddresses.city", street: "$postalAddresses.street."}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up, Tom. I was not aware of this, though I did know about $unwind in a theoretical manner. The query has worked.

Comment: glad to hear, note that i had a typo in my group cond, it is now fixed.